# Unable to connect to remote service at http://serveraddress:12291 on workflow manager installation

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

I am trying  to install Workflow Manager 2013 on a multi server environment , I have 2 WFE and 1 app.

I installed Workflow Manager on app server with the CU for Service Bus and Workflow Manager. After the installation I checked the bindings in IIS and tried browsing `http://localhost:12291`, it gives error .

When I opened IE it as an administrator and then tried opening the site it gave me the page with XML . So I proceeded with registering the Workflow using powershell command :

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite 'http://uatsp' -WorkflowHostUri "http://uatsp:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp -Force
```

and I started getting error :

> Unable to connect to remote service at `http://uatsp:12291/SharePoint`

In the logs I get :

> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowEndpointNotFoundException: Unable to connect to the remote service at

I checked in Central administration and there is `Workflow manager proxy` in Service applications .

When I click them I  get `Workflow not connected`

> SharePoint 2013 workflow requires a compatible workflow service configured with SharePoint such as Workflow Manager. The workflow service is either not installed or not configured. Follow this link to find out how to set up workflow

I used TechNet blogs to install workflow and I also used [this blog](http://charulbhargava.blogspot.ae/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager.html) .

Comment: Is your workflow service application proxy associated with central admin in the default proxy group? Add this to the central administration URL "/_admin/ApplicationAssociations.aspx?View=All" and check if Workflow Service Application Proxy is in the "Default" group.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that by default, the Workflow Manager Config wizard adds I workflow Service Application Proxy in Central Admin by itself. So when I registered the service, I ended up with 2 proxies.

The solution I got is to **delete both proxie**s and **re-run** the `Register-SPWorkflowService` command with the `-force` attribute

Answer (score 0):

What I needed to do was installing WF manager on WFE1  then on WFE2, connect it to existing farm and then on the App server I installed Workflow Client.